# First and Second Derivative of a logarithmic function within another logarithmic function

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve for the first and second derivative of this function but I'm a little stuck. Thank you.

f(x) = ln(7-ln x)

Answer (score 1):

We just use the chain rule
$$f(x) = \ln (7-\ln x) = \ln g(x) \qquad g(x) = 7-\ln x \\ f^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)} \cdot g^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{7-\ln x}\cdot -\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{x(7-\ln x)}$$

The second derivative uses the same idea (but is conceptually simpler).

Comment: So then would the critical numbers for this derivative be e^7 and 0?